# Implications of CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION for Amazon S3

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3

I am using a curl library to upload images to Amazon S3. However, becuse CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is set to true and open_basedir is enabled, this throws an error:

> CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an
>   open_basedir is set

I understand that I could disable open_basedir or use one of the workarounds at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php, but I have instead set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = false` as a test.

The image upload to S3 still seems to work, but I am concerned that something may break down the line. Are there any implications that I should be aware of?